# MySQL root privilege not restorable

Tags: mysql, permissions

I really tried out everything I already found here.
So I think i forgot my root password,... after getting into rescue mode with 
--skip-grant-tables I found out, that there is no root user (anymore?).

so,.. yeah, great,.. .how to solve it no privileged user is there anymore?
I can't create one with "CREATE USER ...' because I'm in skip-grant-tables mode,...

So I decided to insert a user manually. Now I have my root user back, with credentials and so on, but I'm not able to grant access to all tables and permissions.

I tried this (I'm connectet to mysql with my 'newly' created root-account):

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Okay ... 
then:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
mysql>
```

What?

```
mysql> select Grant_priv, Super_priv from user where User='root';
+------------+------------+
| Grant_priv | Super_priv |
+------------+------------+
| Y          | Y          |
+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I don't get it....

Yes, I flushed the privilege. I restarted the service multiple times. But still I'm not able to grant access to my root user.

Please help :(

Comment: From memory, there is 3 root user in the mysql table a you need to change the 3 of them. IF i run `MariaDB [mysql]> select count(*) from mysql.user where User='root';`i get 3. One for localhost, one for 127.0.0.1 (essentialy the same) and one for host `::1` if that can be of any help.

Comment: Also, i remember doing a service restart too but mysqld was still running in the background. I had to kill all processes and restart the service after. (or reboot the machine altogether). Sorry can't help you more, not the kind of stuff i do everyday but a little `top` might be of help.

Comment: Sorry, thant didn't work. In MySQL I only have one line of that root user. It has rights to ANY host. Rebooted = no changes.